# How to separate kinder surprise eggs?

Tags: puzzle

Andrew and Bob got $37$ kinder surprise eggs. In $20$ of them there are cars and in $17$ there are hippo. Unfortunately, it is not known which surprise in the each eggs.
They want to divide all the eggs among themselves, not opening them so that the eggs with cars they have equally for each. To do this, they can use a magic wand that changes the surprise inside the egg to the opposite (car for a hippo, and a hippo for a car). They can use a magic wand several times.  How can they solve this problem?

Comment: A closely related Question was [The Blind Man and Coins Puzzle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/659481/the-blind-man-and-coins-puzzle).

Comment: This is an “aha” problem. Notice that the goal *isn’t* for Andrew and Bob to end up with 10 cars each, but only that they end up with the same number of cars.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, Andrew takes $17$ of the eggs. Of course there is no way for him to know how many cars he got - so let's say he got $n$ cars.

Next, Bob takes the remaining $20$ eggs. Because there were originally $20$ cars, he got $20 - n$ cars. That means he has $20 - (20 - n) = n$ hippos.

They then use the magic wand on all of Bob's eggs. This turns all of Bob's hippos into cars - so Bob now has $n$ cars, the same as Andrew.

As a side note: This had nothing to do with the numbers $20$ and $17$ in particular - this strategy will work with any number. You just have to have Andrew start by taking a number of eggs equal to the number of hippos.